# I am not able to create Navigation Drawer activity for my application

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIEeK.jpg)When I Right click on app > new > activity > navigation drawer activity, nothing happens! it just creates a xml file in menu directory. i tried deleting android studio and user preferences files and reinstalling it, but still having the same problem.

When i try to create Navigation Drawer Activity by name "HomeActivity" following above steps. it just creates a xml file in menu directory and ".HomeActivity" in AndroidManifest.xml file( which gives error).
But HomeActivity.java and activity_home.xml and other fragment and navigation activity is not creating.

i have attached my AndroidManifest.xml code.
Note:- i am currently using AndroidStudio 4.0 version and Java 8 jdk.

Comment: Hi. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: does anyone found the solution

Answer (score -1):

I've been working with Android Studio 3.6.3 and everything worked fine for me. Try to download it and test if the problem persists.

https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/3.6.3.0/android-studio-ide-192.6392135-windows.exe

The link looks weird, but it's the official one (from Android Studio's website).

Hope it works!

Comment: I have downloaded 3.6.3 version. When i tried to open my project , build failed. it says   
 "This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 4.0 or newer."